# DropDownList Client-side onchange stops Server-side SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, drop-down-menu

How to call the clientside script and server-side script at same time.
I cannot able to use both at same time.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModule" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlModule_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

In Page_Load

```
ddlModule.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:return validateDropDown('" + ddlModule.ClientID + "');");
```

if client script execute then server side not working.

Please Help..

Thanks,

Comment: Adding an 'onchange' attribute to a dropdownlist doesn't seem to fire anything in the client side. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution: in your `validateDropDown` JavaScript function you can postback the page

```
<script language='Javascript'>
__doPostBack('__Page', 'MyCustomArgument');
</script>
```

Here is a reference link [How to call Postback from Javascript](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1521-How-call-Postback-from-Javascript.aspx)